# Dart pubs rename failed

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I get the following error when running 'pub get'

```
IO  : Deleting directory C:\Users\HANGS_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pub_08dcace7-6d3d-11e3-bed4-2016d87b1a0e.
IO  : Renaming directory C:\Users\hangs_000\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\_temp\dir08dcace6-6d3d-11e3-bed4-2016d87b1a0e to C:\Users\hangs_000\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\http-0.9.2
FINE: Clean up system cache temp directory C:\Users\hangs_000\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\_temp.
IO  : Deleting directory C:\Users\hangs_000\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\_temp.
ERR : Rename failed
FINE: directory_impl.dart 208                                                                              _Directory.renameSync
    | e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\io.dart 321            renameDir
    | e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\io.dart 325            renameDir
    | e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\source\hosted.dart 99  HostedSource.get.<fn>.<fn>
    | dart:isolate                       

                                                              _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

I have tried deleting the pub cache and my package directory

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug:  [Pub install fails with 'Deletion failed'](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11887)